# How to use AWS REST API with Authentication 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've tried using the Signature 4 for authenticating API request for AWS SQS.

**But it gives access denied whenever I try to use it.** I followed this link to create the signature.

http://www.javaquery.com/2016/01/aws-version-4-signing-process-complete.html#comment-2565627657

Example for request is:

```
http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/testQueue/?Action=ReceiveMessage&MaxNumberOfMessages=5&VisibilityTimeout=15&AttributeName=All&Version=2012-11-05&Expires=2014-04-18T22%3A52%3A43PST&AUTHPARAMS
```

This AUTHPARAMS is send in an request header which is as follow:

```
Header : Authorization
Value : Authorization=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/20160609/us-west-2/sqs/aws4_request&SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date&Signature=257f882dfdsf6dd8406dfgde8gfhgfh5c8628c23baf7bf4c1faa782
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how to set it up and send the request? I am not getting where am I going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your region for the SQS it is "us-east-1" and in Authparams it is "us-west-2"

Comment: @Edward : the request is just example request.. actual request contain the same region. Actual request is :
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/QueueName/?Action=ReceiveMessage&MaxNumberOfMessages=5&VisibilityTimeout=15&AttributeName=All;&Version=2012-11-05&Expires=2014-04-18T22%3A52%3A43PST

Comment: What permissions have you created for this user in IAM? Signing the request just validates the user and the request (authentication), does not relate to whether you are authorized to take the action (authorization).